# how to change apache camel timer polling period dynamically

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I am using apache camel timer component in my route. I need to change the period polling interval dynamically. I have a business method which will return some time interval and it will be different depending on logic. I have to pass this to Timer so that my timer should poll according to this interval. I don't want to start and stop the route with new interval as its performance hit.
I want one timer route for which period has to be set dynamically.

Comment: You could try getting the endpoint from the Camel Context and manipulating it directly whenever you need the interval to change.

Comment: Dont stop and start try suspend and resume.

Comment: Can you give some idea about the business method? like based on which data(availability of file or based on some message it receives etc)

Answer (score 1):

The timer cannot be changed at runtime, as its using the JDK java.util.Timer which cannot be changed.

You can use camel-quartz which allows changing the scheduler at runtime, which you can do using JMX. There is also a Quartz plugin in hawtio - http://hawt.io/plugins/quartz/ - that allows you to change the scheduler using a web UI.

Comment: Hi my application is not UI based and there will not be any user intervention.

Comment: If I use quartz will it support JTA/XA transaction. I read some blog that quartz has issues with XA. when event is fired I will be reading a record from database and routing to other database or websphere mq with different resource managers. Eg : from(quartzuri).routeId("testId").process(new Processor() {
     public void process(Exchange e) {
      //read the record from database
     }).transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED") will this work with quartz.

Comment: Hi Claus Ibsen , Any suggestion on my question related to quartz ?